# What is the behavior of null/empty value in compound shard key?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-3.4

> I have a shard key based on **{Field1:1,Field2:1}** where **Field2 can
>   be null**. So if two documents have **same value for Field1 and
>   null/empty value of Field2** then are they considered to **belong to
>   the same shard key/non split-able**??

Comment: ,Once you shard a collection, the shard key and the shard key values are immutable.

Comment: @Stennie :  Does empty and missing mean same thing? If empty means Field2:"" then why is it treated so differently than null? Wondering ...

Comment: To be clear, fields in the shard key must be present in all documents and have a value (so in your case, `Field1` and `Field2` must always be set). Values include null or empty string, although if those are common in one of your shard key fields you should consider a field with [more cardinality](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#shard-key-cardinality).

Comment: @Stennie: Yup I got the cardinality thing. Just that you mentioned the field cannot be empty so was little confused. Now I am sure by that you meant the field must be present  and it can have any values : null/empty.  Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB 'null' is just another value so two documents that have the same values for field1 (some non-null) and same value for field2 (null) have the same value for the shard key and will always be in the same "chunk".

Answer (score -1):

As per `MongoDB BOL` [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/) The shard key determines the distribution of the collection’s [documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-document) among the cluster’s [shards](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-shard). The shard key is either an indexed [field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-field) or indexed [compound](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-compound-index) fields that exists in every document in the collection.

MongoDB [partitions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-data-partition) data in the collection using ranges of shard key values. Each range defines a non-overlapping range of shard key values and is associated with a [chunk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-chunk).

MongoDB attempts to distribute chunks evenly among the shards in the cluster. The shard key has a direct relationship to the effectiveness of chunk distribution.

> **Note:** Once you shard a collection, the shard key and the shard key values are **immutable**; i.e. You cannot select a `different shard key` for
>   that `collection`. You cannot `update` the `values` of the `shard key fields`.

Comment: Just a copy of the documentation without any relevance to the behavior of shard keys.